# Which computer assisted translation format should I use for a ColdFusion site?

Tags: localization, coldfusion, internationalization

I am creating a multilingual site that will need to support at minimum five different languages, including Korean and Chinese. The site language is ColdFusion, so Java is the native language. I want to make the site as easy as possible for the next programmer to update, and for third-party translators to use tools that will work easier for them than digging through a SQL database.

So far I have come across Resource Bundles, GNU's GetText, and TMX.

Which do you recommend and why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Resource Bundles are my preferred choice. I have found they are kind to future programmers, self documenting in many ways, and, make it easy to manage subcontracting the translators. They have kept things simple, reduced my technology stack and have yet to fail me.

Good luck with your project, and, thank you for making life easier for the next developer. I wish more people thought like you.

Answer (score 2):

comparing rb & TMX is an apples to oranges comparison. rb & getText are sort of the same thing. TMX is a format for computer aided xlation & xfer between tools/translators.

what you seem to be overlooking is manging rb or whatever. for large i18n projects rb get big & complicated. if you have multiple translation vendors (not recommended if at all possible) it all becomes like herding cats (what's translated, in what languages, by what translator, etc.). find a management tool you like (icu4j's rbmanager is what we normally use, jason sheedy's rbman is pretty decent too) then see what it uses.

and once again (in case anybody's forgotten my "bah humbug" stance) i urge you **not** to use machine translators like google or bing for anything serious. people could die.

Comment: I do like rbmanager, and found it to be excellent. I just wanted to know the differences between RB and formats such as gettext, in general. I apologize that I stated TMX, it was just that during my small amount of online research, TMX was stated along with the other translations. Thank you for clearing that up.

Answer (score 2):

An internationalisation library for Adobe ColdFusion which uses the resource bundle package style that Adobe Flex uses.

http://resourcemanager.riaforge.org/

Answer (score 1):

You may try [i18n support](http://ortus.svnrepository.com/coldbox/trac.cgi/wiki/cbi18n) by MVC framework like [ColdBox](http://www.coldboxframework.com/).

Comment: Although Coldbox would be great, the other programmers at my location are not entirely for using a framework (despite the benefits).

Comment: ColdBox's i18n plugin uses resource bundles. It's nice not to have to reinvent the wheel. Luis and the CB team have done some great work.

Comment: Yes, Aaron, I'm sure they have. However, I do not currently have the say at my place of employment to utilize a framework, hence my comment prior to yours.

Answer (score 0):

Use i18N Resource Bundles for coldfusion.  Paul Hastings has a great set of cfcs at: http://www.sustainablegis.com/blog/cfg11n/index.cfm?mode=cat&catid=F46401DD-50FC-543B-1F1FBE4F2BAD6B83

Comment: I have seen that, and it looks excellent. However, I was asking for a comparison of that and other translation formats. I can only assume that you are suggesting Resource Bundles, but is there any particular reason why?

Comment: Resource bundles come from the Java underbelly of Coldfusion.  They're industry tested, load/pressure proofed, and quite simple to use and maintain.  They tie in to coldfusion's locale features easily.

One alternative to internationalization is to build your own language table, and eval() based cf_function to plug in all the values for you.  While this might appear simpler, it will quickly fail as Evaluate is an expensive function in general and is no different in ColdFusion.

Is there anything holding you back from Resource bundles?  I was hesitant at first but it's the right thing.

Comment: Nothing holding me back from resource bundles, I just wanted to know the difference between them and the other formats. I definitely wasn't considering the database route. Thank you for your answer about RB!

Comment: No worries, it sounded like you were ok with the Resource bundles so you had me curious to maybe another option that wasn't mentioned here.. The database front end to generating RB's is quite handy, but beyond that it's not ideal.. enjoy