# What's the most basic way to have resource files (for language) in Coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion, internationalization

I've searched a bid for tutorials on creating resource bundle files for Coldfusion (or internationalization). I'm finding stuff for Coldbox and Mura quite easily. I've also found tutorials for Java, but I wonder how they apply in this situation.

However, I'm using Fusebox 3 and Coldfusion 8. I'm not convinced that these would be easily applicable in this situation.

What would be the most basic way to use resource files for language purposes?

Comment: This may help: http://wiki.coldbox.org/wiki/Plugins:i18n.cfm

Comment: @Henry I don't need to be running Coldbox for this? I could implement this anywhere?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368551/which-computer-assisted-translation-format-should-i-use-for-a-coldfusion-site

Comment: Hey, accidentally bumped into this http://www.forta.com/books/0321679199/CFWACK9-2-echapters.pdf see if it helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [JavaRB](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&extid=1010326) CFC along with [I18NUtil](http://code.google.com/p/cfi18n/source/browse/trunk/i18nUtil.cfc?spec=svn2&r=2). JavaRB can be used to load pure java resource bundles and I18NUtil contains lots of number/currency/other functions. We've used them successfully for many years.

You can load the resources into the APPLICATION scope which makes key retrieval extremely quick. You just need a way to reload them once you add/updated the resource files.

Comment: I will give JavaRB a try. Thanks!